# How to change screen orientation of my samsung froyo device

Tags: 2.2-froyo, orientation

Any one knows how to change device orientation, from portrait to landscape. I'm new here, thanks in advanced for any help! :)

Comment: Which Samsung device do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you just tilt the device.  On my Samsung Galaxy S, you should also have rotation enabled (pull down the notification bar, it's the far right icon).